# object型の列をdatetime64型へ変換したい

Tags: python, pandas

markt_train_dfというデータフレームを扱っています。データ型は以下の通りとなっております。
今、一番上の”time"という列のデータ型をobjectからdatetime64[ns, UTC]に変更しなければならないのですが、どのようにすれば"time"のデータ型のみを変更したdataframeを取得できるでしょうか。
初歩的な質問で大変恐縮ですがご教授いただきましたら幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**time列**にどのような形式のデータが入っているかにもよりますが、
通常であれば

```
market_train_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(market_train_df['time'])
```

で変換できるかと思います

一応サンプル

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2019/01/24 18:00',
                           '2019/01/24 19:00:00.1234',
                           '201901242000',
                           '21:00',
                           '2019/1/25'],
                   'other_format_time': ['01220100',
                                         '01220200',
                                         '01220300',
                                         '01220400',
                                         '01220500'],
                   'unixtime': [1548105800,
                                1548105900,
                                1548106000,
                                1548106100,
                                1548106200]})
# 大抵の文字列は変換できるはず
print(pd.to_datetime(df['time']))
#0   2019-01-24 18:00:00.000000
#1   2019-01-24 19:00:00.123400
#2   2019-01-24 20:00:00.000000
#3   2019-01-24 21:00:00.000000
#4   2019-01-25 00:00:00.000000
#Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# 特殊な文字列の場合は format を指定する
print(pd.to_datetime(df['other_format_time'], format='%m%d%H%M'))
#0   1900-01-22 01:00:00
#1   1900-01-22 02:00:00
#2   1900-01-22 03:00:00
#3   1900-01-22 04:00:00
#4   1900-01-22 05:00:00
#Name: other_format_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# UnixTimeの場合も変換可能
print(pd.to_datetime(df['unixtime'], unit='s'))
#0   2019-01-21 21:23:20
#1   2019-01-21 21:25:00
#2   2019-01-21 21:26:40
#3   2019-01-21 21:28:20
#4   2019-01-21 21:30:00
#Name: unixtime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

詳細は以下を参考にしてください

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html